# tkinter clicks on child do not propagate to parent

Tags: python, tkinter

Why doesn't clicking on a child element propagate to the parent?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def handler(event):
    print('clicked at', event.x, event.y)

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
label = Label(frame, text="Label")
frame.bind('<Button-1>', handler)
frame.pack()
label.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run that, clicking on the label doesn't fire the handler.  I've understood that events propagate to parents by default and if you didn't want that, you'd have to return "break"

Answer (score 5):

**You are incorrect in your original understanding that events propagate to their parent. They do not.**

Admittedly, there's an edge case for widgets which are a direct descendant of a toplevel or root window. Even there, it's not that they are propagating to their parent, but rather they are being handled by other bindings as defined by the bind tags, and by default every widget has it's toplevel window as one of it's bind tags.

If you want to set a binding to work everywhere you can use the `bind_all` method, since each widget has an "all" bindtag by default.  Another option is to give several widgets the same bindtag (using the `bindtags` method), then bind to that bindtag with `bind_class`. Which choice you make depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

bindtags are extremely powerful -- arguably more powerful than any binding mechanisms from any other toolkit. For example, if you *need* to have events propagate you can do that by adjusting the bindtags of every widget to include all of its ancestors. In my experience, however, such shenanigans is rarely ever needed.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I'm still a bit confused tho.  In this example, you see two lines printed when you press anything other than o and k because pressing o or k propagates up to the root window too.

`def handler(event):
    print("Keystroke '{0}' ({1}) {2} ".format(event.char, len(event.char), event.keycode)) 

def handler2(event):
    print("RootKeystroke '{0}' ({1}) {2} ".format(event.char, len(event.char), event.keycode))

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("o", handler)
frame.bind("k", handler)
root.bind("<Key>", handler2)`

Comment: Horray, I'm glad I was right :).  (+1 for proposing alternate solutions).

Comment: @donrosszx: what you ask in your comment is different than what you ask in your question. Maybe you should make a separate question, or clarify this one. Bottom line: events don't propagate, but they may have multiple handlers. These multiple handlers may correspond to parent windows but maybe not. The root window is a special case. My advice is to try to rephrase your question in terms of what you actually want to do. Do you want to propagate events to parent widgets, or do you want to prevent events from being handled from multiple handlers (or something else entirely)?

Comment: Folks, I'm sorry I haven't been clear with what I want.  My desired behavior is that if I click anywhere in the frame, I want to see the position.  Right now, when I click on the label inside the frame, I don't see the position relative to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaken.  `"break"` causes that event to not propagate to other handlers for the widget that was clicked on.

In other words, if you bound your action to `label` and then you bound another action to the first button onto `label`, both callbacks will be called (unless you return `"break"` from the first one to be called.)

I'm not sure of a workaround though ... (We might need to wait for BryanOakley to show up ;)

Comment: Hey mgilson, I think my description was misleading.  I was saying that  I thought it would propagate up to the frame by default.  That's my desired behavior.  I was surprised that it didn't even though there's no 'break' in the code

Comment: @donrosszx -- I understand that's what you were saying.  What I'm saying is that events don't propagate to their parents and that the purpose of `"break"` is to prevent the next callback from being called (bound to that particular event on that particular widget).

Comment: @donrosszx - I suppose that if you want to propagate an event up to the parent, you can just switch that out on the event object and then call the callback again:  `def handler(event): event.widget = event.widget.master; if event.widget: handler(event)`