# Click event through another widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Frame() which contains another Label() in it.

The Frame() has a bound event that moves it when dragged.
The problem is that the Label is "on the way" so when clicking over the Label,
it wont pick up the event on underneath widget.

Is there a way to make Label(), so its clicks will be ignored and go right through?

Sorry for messy question. Here's some sample code:

```
titlebar = Frame(app, height=20, background='#333333')
titlebar.pack(side='top', fill=X, padx=4, pady=4)
titlebar.bind('<Button-1>', drag_window) # This event should also be triggered through label widget

titlebar_label = Label(titlebar, text='Node Handler',
                   background='#333333', foreground='#ffffff')
titlebar_label.pack(side='left')
```

Comment: You should post a minimal code example that lets others replicate/tinker with the problem. Is there an issue with binding the label with the same binding as the frame?

Comment: I did that and it worked ofcourse, but it's a messy way and just thought of ascing if there were a way to not really disable a widget, but to make it ignore mouse clicks. Kind of to disable "bounding" or "collision" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
titlebar.bind_all('<Button-1>', drag_window)
```

may be what you are looking for, from:
[tkinter clicks on child do not propagate to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356068/tkinter-clicks-on-child-do-not-propagate-to-parent)

Attempt 2 to localize the click through:

```
titlebar_label.bindtags(('.titlebar_label','Label', 'clickthru','.','all'))
titlebar.bind_class('clickthru', '<Button-1>', drag_window)
```

and change the 'bind_all' back to 'bind'.

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit -- this won't just let events on the label "go through", it actually adds the button 1 binding to _all_ widgets.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and I have to withdraw this solution sadly. I guess I just have to add a bind on the label afterall too.